# How can I get the tags of stackoverflow for solr index?

Tags: nutch

Recently, I used nutch-1.11 and solr-4.10.4 to set up a crawler, I can crawl data by sequential nutch commands, but now my problem is how can I to fetch the specified data, like tags of questions of stackoverflow for example, then I can use these data for solr indexing for my some purpose? I try to configure and modify the "local/conf/nutch-site" but doesn't work for me, I'm a newer for Nnutch!

Answer (score 0):

Nutch fetches urls, so what you could do is point it to a page which might contain all the links to the questions with that tag.

For example
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nutch?sort=newest, this page contains links to all questions having Nutch as the tag. Now by crawling 2 or more rounds will make Nutch fetch all outlinks from this page.